Finding out why Mac has frozen for hours before finally waking up
On my MBP running Mojave, I sometimes experience a weird issue that I can't pin down. At night or anytime I leave it unattended, the monitor turns off as expected, but can't wake up in the morning.
It's not frozen as the keyboard "Shift lock" key still lights up when pressed.
And after letting it sit for 18 hours (horrible headache so I couldn't work), all of a sudden the monitor turns on, fans spin up. It hasn't restarted, just got out of its coma.
Is there a way to know what causes these prolonged unavailability periods?

Can you take a comprehensive sysdiagnose of the mac? You can do that by pressing Control-Option-Command-Shift-Period(see its manpage). Then when you boot it normally again you can upload the tar it generated in your /tmp to some file-sharing device so we can take a look. It is very hard to diagnose your issue without any debug info.

Indeed. Here's the link: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/4fg9KL0J#link. This occurred again 2024-05-24, around 0:28-0:35 when I had to force-restart it.

Thank you. I suspect you may find relevant info in "pmset_everything.txt" 's pmset -g log section.  It contains logs like "display is turned off" and what reason caused its wake/darkwake &c. From the log, I noticed that the logs stopped after 5-23 22:27:17 and only continued after you restarted it, which may not be normal. Sorry I am not an expert in this, but you may have some success by changing pmset settings. Also, you did not take the sysdiagnose while your mac is in the "woke but monitor black" time, but after your restart, which limited the useful information in the debug log!

I’d gladly try to get the debug data you say, but when the computer is in this state, I can’t even reach it through SSH. A connection request from another computer doesn’t timeout, but never completes. I can confirm the logs stopping for a long time isn’t normal as the computer is never turned off.

An update FWIW: it appears to be somehow linked to Firefox. On the rare times I don't have my browser open, sleep and wake work properly. May or may not be linked to my previous question
